# how to configure android annotations to generate java code with utf-8 encoding

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, annotations, android-annotations

I have an Android Project with annotations from Android Annotations [[https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations]](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations). My Java original files are encoded in UTF-8. I run into errors because the Java Files generated by Android Annotations from the original ones during the build are not encoded in UTF-8. How can i configure android annotations to generate intermediate java files with utf-8 encoding ?

I use Android Studio with this Gradle file :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }

  dependencies {
    // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // Since Android's Gradle plugin 0.11, you have to use android-apt >= 1.3
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

dependencies {
  apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
  compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.9'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

apt {
  arguments {
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
  }
}


android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "android.pam"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
  }

}
```

Comment: My generated files are UTF-8, but i am on Mac. What platform do you use?

Comment: I use windows 10. I remarked that the problem is around the annotations @ViewById. When in a fragment F i write [@ViewById activité] with an accent, then in the generated file F_, we'll find an instruction ... findById(activité) (or something) and [activité] won't be in UTF-8 and the compiler then notifies an error.

Comment: more precisely [@ViewById(R.id.activité) TextView activité] ...

Comment: Please raise an issue on AA's GitHub. We currently use the platform default encoding, but it is possible to add a new flag to AA to specify the desired encoding.